# How to force Tensorflow to show a simple linear regression prediction result?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a simple linear regression question as below:

[image]

My codes are as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_xs=np.array([[0,0,1],[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[0,1,1]])
batch_ys=np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3, 1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

y = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

learning_rate = 0.05

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.Session()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)

sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

Prediction:

```
x0=np.array([[1.,0.,0.]])
x0=np.float32(x0)
y0=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x0,W) + b)
print(y0)
```

However, `print(y0)` shows `Tensor("Softmax_2:0", shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)` instead of a figure. I expect `y0` would be around 0.99.

I tried `y0.eval()`, but I got `ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using 'eval()': No default session is registered.`.

How can I make a change to obtain the result? Thanks!

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to get things to print out while writing TensorFlow code. Of course, there’s the classic Python built-in, print (Or the function print(), if we’re being Python 3 about it). And then there’s TensorFlow’s print function, tf.Print (notice the capital P).

When working with TensorFlow, it’s important to remember that everything is ultimately a graph computation. This means that if you print a TensorFlow operation using Python’s print, it will simply show a description of what that operation is, since no values have been passed through it yet. It will also often show the dimensions that are expected to be in that node, if they’re known.

If you want to print the values that are ‘flowing’ through a particular part of the graph as it’s being executed, then we need to turn to using tf.Print.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I tried `sess.run(tf.Print(y0,[y0]))` and just `tf.Print(y0,[y0])`, but both of them give blank. Did I miss something?

Comment: x = tf.get_variable('x', [10, 5]),
x = tf.Print(x, [x]),
 
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(),
sess.run(x)

Comment: Thanks. But no matter I tried your code, or I replaced all `x` by `y0` in your code, I still have error. If I run `y0 = tf.get_variable('y0', [10, 5])`, I got `ValueError: Variable y0 already exists, disallowed`. Any ideas?